# ORACLE SQL - Can't get Trigger to obtain Sum/Count of values from that table that is being updated

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Ok I got a couple of practice exercises from class and I found one that I couldn't figure out, even though it sounds pretty simple. I have this tables. I want to make a trigger that after every time I update or insert a value into the product table, it updates the class table with the count of how many products belong to that class, and the sum of the prices.

At first I tried using FOR EACH ROW, but I couldn't figure out how to make it so that it reads the product table new product values for the class of the new entry without 'mutating', as I was trying to read the product table that was being updates/inserted into. Couldn't figure out even if there was a right way to set up :new. and :old. for this purpose.

Tried cursors that checked the product table and selects into variables for count and sum, but it was the same problem, the whole 'mutating' problem.

Now I got it without the FOR EACH ROW but it Counts and Sums all the products and prices for all classes. I can't figure out how to make it work for each class individually. I though maybe a loop and a counter that increased based on the max class, but that seems over-complicated.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
drop table class        cascade constraints;
drop table provider     cascade constraints;
drop table product      cascade constraints;


CREATE TABLE class(
class           number(5)       constraint  pk_class primary key,
description     varchar2(20)    constraint  nn1_class CHECK(description = INITCAP(description) AND description IS NOT NULL),
tot_product     number(5)       constraint  nn2_class CHECK (tot_product >=0  AND tot_product IS NOT NULL),
tot_price       number(12,2)    constraint  nn3_class CHECK (tot_price >=0  AND tot_price IS NOT NULL),
constraint      pk1_class       CHECK (class >=0)
);


INSERT INTO class VALUES(1,'Description 1', 0, 0);
INSERT INTO class VALUES(2,'Description 2', 0, 0);
INSERT INTO class VALUES(3,'Description 3', 0, 0);
INSERT INTO class VALUES(4,'Description 4', 0, 0);
INSERT INTO class VALUES(5,'Description 5', 0, 0);


CREATE TABLE provider(
provider    number(5)       constraint  pk_provider primary key,
description varchar2(20)    constraint  nn1_provider    CHECK(description = INITCAP(description) AND description IS NOT NULL),
constraint  pk1_provider    CHECK (provider >=0)
);

INSERT INTO provider VALUES(1,'Description 1');
INSERT INTO provider VALUES(2,'Description 2');
INSERT INTO provider VALUES(3,'Description 3');
INSERT INTO provider VALUES(4,'Description 4');
INSERT INTO provider VALUES(5,'Description 5');


CREATE TABLE product(
product         number(5)       constraint  pk_product      primary key,
description     varchar2(20)    constraint  nn1_product CHECK (description = INITCAP(description) AND description IS NOT NULL),
price           number(12,2)    constraint  nn2_product CHECK (price >=0        AND price   IS NOT NULL),
available       number(5)       constraint  nn3_product CHECK (available >=0    AND available IS NOT NULL),
class           number(5)       constraint  fk1_product     references class        NOT NULL,           
provider        number(5)       constraint  fk2_product references provider NOT NULL,   
constraint      pk1_product CHECK (product >=0)
);




CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tot_class
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON product

DECLARE
e_tot_product   number(5);  
e_tot_price     number(12,2);

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(product) INTO e_tot_product
    FROM product
    WHERE class = class; 

SELECT SUM(price) INTO e_tot_price 
    FROM product
    WHERE class = class;


UPDATE class SET tot_product = e_tot_product, tot_price= e_tot_price WHERE class = class;
END;
/


INSERT INTO product VALUES(1,'Description 1', 100, 10, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(2,'Description 2', 100, 10, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(3,'Description 3', 100, 10, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(4,'Description 4', 100, 10, 4, 5);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(5,'Description 5', 100, 10, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that to use the `MERGE` statement in the trigger like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TOT_CLASS
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON PRODUCT 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
BEGIN

MERGE INTO class oldclass
using 
( 
SELECT a.class,COUNT(b.product) tot_poduct,sum(b.price) tot_price
    FROM product b
    join
    class a
    on a.class = b.class
    group by a.class
)    newclass
on (oldclass.class = newclass.class)
when matched then 
update set oldclass.tot_product = newclass.tot_poduct,
oldclass.tot_price = newclass.tot_price;

END;
/
```

here if the product class is updated then, we have to recheck the old product count and total price also. hence the above statement will take such problems. Still i am not sure about the performance while on large data set. I would suggest timely call of merge statement reside inside the trigger using `DBMS_JOBS` or you can use tuning methods on the same.

Comment: Thank you, wasn't aware of the merge function for this.

Answer (score 1):

So, you discovered mutation.  First off, if you find that you need to deal with mutation, ask yourself why.  I would suspect a flaw in the data model or application design.  However, having said that, let's talk a bit about mutation and how to avoid it.

Mutation happens when you have a row-level trigger and you're referencing the table upon which the trigger is built, in the trigger code, and a single SQL statement is affecting more than one row in the table.  Oracle doesn't know how to maintain consistency, since each row will re-execute the trigger.

The standard way to handle mutation is to write a package, with three functions and a package level array.  The three functions are initialize(), save_row(), and process().

You need three steps to make it work.  First, you need a statement level BEFORE trigger to call the initialize() function, to initialize a package level array.  Then a row-level BEFORE trigger will call the save_row() function which will save the current row (pk or rowid) into the array, and finally a statement-level AFTER trigger to call process() to read the rows in the array and process the data accordingly.

If you go to http://asktom.oracle.com/ and search for 'table mutation', you'll find tons of answered questions, complete with sample code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will check that site out.